# In flutter how to set the width of the text field

Tags: flutter

Creating a desktop app and the width of the text field is too log how to reduce the width of the textfield

[image]

```
  body: Center(
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _firstNumberController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration:
                      const InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Number'),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _secondNumberController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration:
                      const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Second Number'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _calculateSum,
                child: const Text('Calculate Sum'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text(
                'Sum: $_sum',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To adjust the width, you could use the width field in a SizedBox with the text field as a child.

```
    const SizedBox(
  width: 100.0,
  child: TextField(
              controller: _secondNumberController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration:
                  const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Second Number'),
            ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the TextField widget in a `Container` or `SizedBox` widget and set the width property of the container or the width property of the SizedBox.

Example -

```
const Container(
  width: 200,
  child: TextField(),
)
```